# Docker compose with Traefik results in 404

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

We are trying to configure api and frontend with `docker-compose` using `Traefik` and we need that both applications are exposed by domain.
With this configuration we get 404 but commented "frontend" lines make api works.
In Traefik dashboard we can see both applications in "HTTP Services" tab as loadbalancer but we have no routers in "Routers" tab.

What we miss?

We also tried using "network" with no luck (receive "gateway time out").

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:latest"
    restart: always
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=myemail" # Let's Encrypt email
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"

    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    container_name: "db"
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypassword
       MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
       MYSQL_USER: myuser
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypassword
    ports:
      - "32769:3306"
  api:
    image: "myregistry/myimage:latest"
    restart: always
    container_name: "api"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"

      - traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.routers.web.middlewares=redirect-to-https
      - traefik.http.routers.web.rule=Host(`mydomainapi`)
      - traefik.http.routers.web.entrypoints=web

      - "traefik.http.routers.websecure.rule=Host(`mydomainapi`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.websecure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.websecure.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"

    depends_on:
      - db
  frontend:
    image: "myregistry/myimagefrontend:latest"
    restart: always
    container_name: "frontend"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.routers.web.middlewares=redirect-to-https
      - traefik.http.routers.web.rule=Host(`mydomainfrontend`)
      - traefik.http.routers.web.entrypoints=web
      
      - "traefik.http.routers.websecure.rule=Host(`mydomainfrontend`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.websecure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.websecure.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"

    depends_on:
      - api

volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local
```